# How to access Button inside "include" layout

Tags: android, layout, include, onclick

Refer to the doc: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

I have a button inside the included layout, how can I access the button? I don't know the id! How can I define the OnClickListener...?

Please help...

Comment: This solution worked for me and it's pretty easy.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69703403/10116694

Answer (score 90):

The id you have with the include tag is assigned to the root View of the included layout.
First get a reference to that View using findViewByid. Then you can call findViewById on that specific View to get a reference to a View inside the layout. So:

```
View myLayout = findViewById( R.id.cell1 ); // root View id from that link
View myView = myLayout.findViewById( R.id.someinnerview ); // id of a view contained in the included file
```

Answer (score 23):

All you need is the id of the parent view:

[image]

In this example, the `LinearLayout` is the parent of the `TextView` I want from the included View.

I can now do this:

```
    View view = findViewById(R.id.include_title_layout);
    TextView titleTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTitleTextView);
    titleTV.setText("Whatever");
```

Answer (score 3):

You do know the id of the include. You can get that complete element, and then get one of its children starting from there.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `include` tags include all the elements in your root layout. So you can always access them using `findViewById` on your Activity.

Suppose you have a `alayout.xml` in which there is a `include` layout. Now in one of your activity A,inside `onCreate` you declared `setContentView(R.layout.alayout)` Now inside your include layout you might have a button with id `myBtn`. You can access that inside `onCreate` in the same way you could access it if it were in main layout: `findViewById(R.id.myBtn)`

Answer (score 1):

i think your mean is NavigationView. you can access to inner layout by this way:

```
NavigationView ngv= (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_id);
View innerview =  ngv.getHeaderView(0);
TextView user_view= (TextView)innerview.findViewById(R.id.nav_name); //any you need
user_view.setText(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me in java

```
        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout_infoProfile"
            layout="@layout/user_info_doctor_profile_layout"
            />



  preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MyConstant.MY_SHARED_PREF,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     View view = mView.findViewById(R.id.layout_infoProfile);  
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(preferences.getString(MyConstant.ROLE,MyConstant.NO_VALUE));
```