# Android data binding attribute not found

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I am trying to replicate this answer: [Setting attribute of child element of included layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013298/setting-attribute-of-child-element-of-included-layout/44691776#44691776)

I have a simple `custom_edit_text.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="hint123" type="String" />
    </data>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/emailField"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:hint="@{hint123}"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:fontFamily="@font/eina_regular"
            android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edit_text_color"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

And I include it in another file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <include
            layout="@layout/custom_edit_text"
            app:hint123="Email"/>
</layout>
```

However the project refuses to compile after a clean & rebuild with the error:

`AAPT: error: attribute hint123 (aka inc.company.appname:hint123) not found.`

Any ideas?

I also have

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

enabled in the app level `build.gradle`

Comment: At a 10 second glance I would say you `Android Studio`/Operating System is **old**, would I be right ?

Comment: Up to date, running 3.3.2 :( good idea tho

Comment: os is newest version of macos

Comment: Rather than `app:hint123="Email"`, pass like this `app:hint123="@{Email}"` in include layout.

Comment: @JeelVankhede that did it, it compiles! However, now when I pass a raw string value, it does not populate in the included view.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think I've hit upon the solution. To activate data binding, you need to use a `@{}` expression, and what's in the braces must be valid Java code. So a literal string must be enclosed in quotes... which must be encoded as `&quot;` inside an XML attribute value. Put it all together and you get:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/custom_edit_text"
    app:hint123="@{&quot;Email&quot;}"/>
```

Data binding *does* work for include files, it's just that the syntax for a literal is a bit convoluted. I had the same issue and this form is working in my project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a very strange behavior. I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: ...or at least a descriptive error message that explains this simple issue

Comment: Excellent explanation of what's going on here. Not sure I would have ever come up with this solution. It's unfortunate that there are no examples of this usage in the layout and bindings expressions docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions.

Comment: I regret to inform everyone that this issue still persist. But it seems that you can do something like `app:hint123='@{"Email"}'` instead if you don't want/need to use &quot;

Answer (score 8):

Bind the variables using `@{ }`

### activity_main.xml

```
</layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".simple.MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main_data_binding"
            bind:name="@{ "Hello World" }" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

### content_view.xml

```
</layout>

    <data>
    <variable
        name="name"
        type="String" />
    </data>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{ name }"/>

 </layout>
```

GL

Comment: bind:name isn't working for me, 'Namespace: 'bind' is not bound'

Comment: Add `xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your parent layout

Comment: Your binding expression is not valid xml

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 alternatives to the quote-escaping solution @big_m provides.

You can single-quote the entire expression and use double-quotes around the string:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/custom_edit_text"
    app:hint123='@{"Email"}'/>
```

Or you can use backticks around the string:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/custom_edit_text"
    app:hint123="@{`Email`}"/>
```

Comment: Much easier on the eyes, @Christopher! I can't believe I didn't think of using the single quotes, but thanks for that! Is there a minimum version of the tools or Java where the backticks work? I looked for information on that format, as I hadn't seen it before, and everything I found said that Java ended up not adopting the backticks, but it does seem to work with the Android SDK 34 toolset.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android 3.1.1. And the following code is working for me, and if you can use it you will be able to reuse "hint" as you desired. I have a slightly altered layout file (custom_edit_text.xml) as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>
    <variable name="cName" type="String" />
    <variable name="user" type="your.package.name.User" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.email}" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.mobile}" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="@{cName.toString()}"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above the second "type" is package name + User class name.

I create the "User" class in a separate file as follows.

```
public class User {
String email;
String mobile;

User(String email, String mobile) {
    this.email = email;
    this.mobile = mobile;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}
}
```

Inside MainActivity inside onCreate() I create the user object create the string and bind them.

```
String email = "xyz@yahoo";
    String mobile = "9999";
    User user = new User(email,mobile);
    CustomEditTextBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.custom_edit_text) ;
    binding.setCName("Yam May");
    binding.setUser(user);
```

And I enabled binding in the app level build.gradle as you did.

A very detailed description about data binding can be found in https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html

Comment: don't forget to add the dataBinding element to your build.gradle file in the app module

android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone misses one detail like me: **you must enclose your parent layout content and the included layout content within "" and ""**. Without that binding is not used in a layout. I had the same issue when I had not enclosed my parent layout with these tags.