# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' in Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm restarting work on a Flutter project from July, and I've been having tons of dependency issues, that I'm slowly working through. However, this one I just can't get rid of.

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Eduardo Campos\Desktop\INESC TEC\ihandu_app-master\iHandUapp\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:40: AAPT: error: attribute android:usesPermissionFlags not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Nothing I do gets me rid of this. I tried cleaning the Flutter build and cache countless times and nothing...

### gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

### Gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
#Tue Jan 19 10:38:00 GMT 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip
```

### project-level build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't recal anything else you might need, but I'll provide you with anything. Needless to say this doesn't seem to have anything to do with flutter...

Also, I'm on Windows, but on MacOS the same problems occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out a variety of things needed to be corrected in both project-level and app-level `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties`.

In `gradle.properties` changed

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

In the **app-level** `build.gradle` changed both

```
compileSdkVersion 28

targetSdkVersion 28
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 31

targetSdkVersion 31
```

In the **project-level** `gradle.build` changed:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

Afterwards, all the dependencies fell in place, `flutter pub get` ran with success and I managed to build my project on my Windows machine. However, on MacOS, some of my dependencies still don't suppor the M1 chip, but the issue is being delt with and until them guess I'll stick to Windows/Linux.

Obs: the package is `flutter_blue` if anyone is curious.

Answer (score 1):

> 40: AAPT: error: attribute android:usesPermissionFlags not found.

You probably have a code issue , there is **usesPermissionFlags** not included correctly . the suggested answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113909/android-data-binding-attribute-not-found) tells your miss using the bind variable `@{ }`

Comment: It wasn't this, at least not for me. I did manage to find out what it was after (more than) a couple of hours. Still, thanks for the assist!