# How to initialize OnClickListener for included layout inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onclicklistener

This is representation of my app layout:
[image: layout]

Where should I create `onClickListeners` for included layouts? I tried inside the fragment but I could not get through with `findViewById`. So I tried from Main Activity but I'm not sure how to get to included layouts from there.

I also tried this inside the fragment:

```
public class MainMenu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

View button_call;

@Override
public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
    button_call = myView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
    button_call.setOnClickListener(this);
    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // implements your things
}


public MainMenu() {

}

}
```

But then Fragment seems to be empty

Fragment XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mainmenu_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="60dp">

<include android:id="@+id/btn_call"
    layout="@layout/call_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<include android:id="@+id/button2"
    layout="@layout/message_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<include android:id="@+id/button3"
    layout="@layout/navigate_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<include android:id="@+id/button4"
    layout="@layout/remind_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: if you want to add that view with in fragment  xml you should include that in fragment class

Comment: @Charuka Ok, but how it should look because my example is not correct

Comment: didn't get what you are asking ? you mean in the code?

Comment: Did you red my question? You can see that I tried to create onclicklisteners but it is not working, so what should I do with it? Also why the -1 point?

Comment: I red it and i asked about your last comment ,not about your question -1 is not from me :) "how it should look because my example is not correct"

Comment: Then yes, how should the listener look in my case? I added the XML of fragment

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4787064/3836513

Comment: @Somachr did you make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps**

1. Create a xml file you want to inclue (eg. web.xml)
2. use include tag in fragment's  xml and connect your layout you need to include using `layout="@layout/`
3. Initialize include tag inside fragment (when you do this make sure about the root tag of your web.xml)
4. Once initializing include tag is done access views inside the layout that included (web.xml) using include tag

**Example**

Here in my fragment I have an `include` tag in it's XML. It connects to my web.xml and ..web.xml's parent tag/ root tag is a  `FrameLayout` ..

Now see how I initialize my `include` tag..(If you do not use the **right root tag** to initialize include,it will crash with a *null pointer*)

I have an id called `g_betta` in my web.xml( XML layout that I included in my fragment)
see how I access that view..

```
public class FragmentAbout extends Fragment  {

private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutConnectedInsideIncludeTag;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment,container,false);


        FrameLayout view  =(FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.include_tag);
        relativeLayoutConnectedInsideIncludeTag = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.g_betta);

        relativeLayoutConnectedInsideIncludeTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes I Found you", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

my fragment xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainmenu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_tag"
        layout="@layout/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

my include--> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/maroon"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ScrollView

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/g_betta"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="HELLO"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"

                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                    android:paddingRight="24dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/girl"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagetwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageone"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/amanda"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
button_call = myView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
button_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                           // write your code here...
                    });
```