# Finding reference to ImageView via an include tag in Android xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I am inflating a layout inside an Android Fragment. The layout to be inflated has the following include tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/middle_multi_game_card"  //NEED TO LOCATE VIEW INSIDE THIS LAYOUT
    android:id="@+id/includeID"
    android:tag="@+id/big_game_card_tag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    />
```

The layout in which the view reference I need has the following structure:

```
//middle_multi_game_card:

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/theroot_"
 >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView   // **I NEED A REFERENCE TO THIS VIEW!**
 android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
 android:tag="thegamepiece_"
</androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

 
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have thought of using a ViewTreeObserver object to get the reference to the view, but I already use the ViewTreeObserver and I don't want to use it again because of performance issues.

I have tried the following inside onViewCreated method:

```
onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{ 
View viewf = view.findViewById(R.id.includeID); //this is found!!
View view_ = viewf.findViewById(R.id.theroot_); //not found at all!
 imageview = 
(AppCompatImageView)view_.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);//not found at all!
}
```

**How can I get a reference to this ImageView via findViewByID or findViewByTag calls?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Button inside "include" layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787008/how-to-access-button-inside-include-layout)

Answer (score 0):

The `findViewByID` will recursively search the whole tree hierarchy. That being that you easily call

```
fragmentView.findViewByID(R.id. my_image_view)
```

in your onCreateView or onViewCreated methods

Updated, try to use:

```
onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{ 
AppCompatImageView imageview = 
(AppCompatImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
}
```

Comment: you mean it will even search inside the layout reference by the include tag?

Comment: I tried this and it did not work:  // inside onviewcreated of the fragment  see:              :  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {   View view_ = view.findViewById(R.id.root);  imageview = view_.findViewByTag("thegamepiece_"); }

Comment: Can you share how do you inflate view in your fragment?

Comment: you are calling a tag, you need to call `AppCompatImageView imageView = view.findViewById< AppCompatImageView>(R.id.my_image_view)`

Comment: '@'Nullable
    '@'Override
    public View onCreateView('@'NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, '@'Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
        main_layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_multi_game_layout,container,false);
        
        return main_layout;
    }                                                   ignore the ' '

Comment: What is `my_multi_game_layout`?

Comment: Have you tried this `AppCompatImageView imageView = view.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.my_image_view)` ?

Comment: android studio is not recognizing:  findviewbyid<>  the notation <> is not recognizable!

Comment: ok, try casting then `AppCompatImageView imageView = (AppCompatImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view)`

Comment: I have done the casting but It did not work. Please read the update of the question. It seems that I can only get a reference to the included layout via its android ID, but this reference cannot get reference to its own root!

Comment: Don't use `findViewByTag`, please use `findViewById`. Please read all my comments carefully. Instead of `findViewByTag` use `AppCompatImageView imageView = (AppCompatImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view)`

Comment: I did used findviewbyID also.. the Logs tell me that the root of the included layout is not found.. it is null!  So, I can not access the imageview!  Read the update part of my question at the bottom of the question see what I did try on the method onviewcreated()

Comment: You DON'T need to access root from included layout, you can use `view` object that you received in `onViewCreated`

Comment: I was using view object from onviewcreated before but It was still telling me that it could not find imageview!  I will try again!

Comment: I updated answear

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to find the correct answer:

in the include tag we have to make sure we have ***the same android id of the root*** view within the included layout!

```
<include layout="@layout/middle_multi_game_card"  //NEED TO LOCATE VIEW INSIDE THIS LAYOUT
android:id="@+id/includeID"
android:tag="@+id/big_game_card_tag"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="6"
/>
```

Now, in the root view of the included layout, which is: middle_multi_game_card.xml

**WE MUST HAVE THE SAME ID OF THE INCLUDE TAG!  WHICH IS FROM ABOVE:  includeID**

*Now, we can access all the views from inside the included layout!*